# Vocabulary size for Word2Vec model significantly lower than vocab size of the list that its based on?

Tags: python, tensorflow, error-handling, word2vec

```
model1 = Word2Vec(words_list_no_dupes, min_count=0,size= 20,workers=3, window =3, sg = 1)
print(model1)
print(len(model1.wv.vocab))
print(model.wv.vectors.shape)
```

output:
Word2Vec(vocab=58, size=20, alpha=0.025)
58
(31752, 20)

However when I check to see the length of the list that the model is formed from

```
print(len(words_list_no_dupes))
```

output:

1906

Whats causing this?
The full code I used to derive remove duplicates from the list is here:

```
words = []
for r in range(0,len(df)):
    temp = []
    for word in nltk.tokenize.WhitespaceTokenizer().tokenize(df["CAR NAME"][r]):   
        temp.append(word.lower())
    words.append(temp)
words_flat_list = [item for sublist in words for item in sublist]

def remove_duplicates(x):
  return list(dict.fromkeys(x))

words_list_no_dupes = remove_duplicates(words_flat_list)
```

Comment: _Whats causing this?_ Causing what? What was the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

The vocabulary size will be the number of unique tokens seen in the training corpus.

It won't have any necessary relationship with the length, in number of texts, in the corpus (`len(words_list_no_dupes)`) – because each text should itself have many words, including many words repeated from other texts.

If your corpus is not like that – if each text is a just one or two words, like a car name, and no words repeat from text to text – then your corpus is not good for word2vec training. Word2vec requires many examples of each word's usage, in contexts with varying mixtures of surrounding words.

That said, your shown output is a little odd: the  `len(model1.wv.vocab)` should be the same size as `model.wv.vectors.shape[0]` – but your output shows 58 then 31,752. Are you sure those are the values from your run?

Also, your 'full code I used to derive remove duplicates from the list' is a bit confusing in intent and effect. You could show, in your question, some examples of what's in the list at the beginning, and end, to perhaps reveal why it's not proper input for `Word2Vec`. For example, what are the 1st few items in `words_flat_list`?

```
print(words_flat_list[0:3])
```

Then, what are the 1st few items in `words_list_no_dupes`?

```
print(words_list_no_dupes[0:3])
```

Is that what you were expecting?

Is that `words_list_no_dupes`, that you're passing into `Word2Vec`, what it expects - which is a Python sequence, where each item is a list-of-string-tokens? (If it's anything else, you should expect weird results.)

Comment: Okay looks like there was a mistake in my code as I printed the shape of "model1" rather than the shape of "model". However, disregarding this I still believe that the vocabulary size and the length of word_list_no_dupes should be the same as word_list_no_dupes is just a list of unique words such as Bentley, Audi, sportback, A8, gt, Aston, Martin, etc...

Comment: And words_flat_list is the same as words_list_no_dupes but it has thousands of duplicate entries for specific cars, for instance there could be 200 "Bentley continental 6.0 gtc" in that list and another 400 "Bentley continental 6.0 gt" as well, but when then I strip all the duplicate entries from it I would end up with another list with "Bentley", "continental", "6.0", "gtc", "gt". So if I printed the length of this list id get 5 wouldn't I? And then the word2vec model would have a vocabulary of 5 too?

Comment: So my plan was to just use word2vec to vectorize each word in every column of my data frame, and the for columns that only have integer values such as year produced and mileage, I wanted to just leave them as is, and then use tensorflow to train the model using the price to train it. So the model would just see a bunch of numbers in columns and not know what they meant and then it would make a prediction for the price and the first time it predicted it would just pick a random number, but then after a few thousand predictions it would get better at predicting the correct price

Comment: I have about 200,000 rows of data so I'd hope that after using 80% as training and 20% as testing, (80% of 200,000 is 160,000) I'd hope to get a really good accuracy for predictions of the price for each car based on the information in the rows. And then if a car came up in future I could just parse it into the model and it would predict the price accurately.

Comment: If `word_list_no_dupes` is just a list of unique car names, then for reasons previously mentioned, it is fairly useless for training a `Word2Vec` model. Word2vec needs repeated words in many varied natural-langauge-like contexts to learn useful vectors. For example, to learn a good vector for 'Bentley', it needs lots of uses of 'Bentley' near other associated words, as if it were discussed alongside features, customers, other models, etc. Your simple short lists of names won't provide that.

Comment: At the current early stage of your project, `Word2Vec` is unlikely to add anything. (If there were long narrative descriptions of the cars, it might help.) Per my suggestion on your other question, I'd recommend you find an existing "predict price with Python ML" tutorials and attempt to adapt those to your problem. Word2Vec may not be relevant – a "one-hot" encoding of your 'names' might be simpler and just as good. And Tensorflow might be overkill at first if you've never done more basic classifiers/regressors before (though you could certainly try it for comparison eventually).